# inherited collection

Tags: java, collections

I have this class

```
public class Room{

private int n_bed;
private float cost;

private Collection<Client> clientlist;

public Room(int n,float c){

    n_bed = n;
    cost = c;

    clientlist = new ArrayList<Client>();
}

}
```

and this class inherited from the above class

```
public class RoomWithBar extends Room{

private Collection<Drink> drinkslist;

public RoomWithBar(int n,float cost){

    super(n,cost);

    drinkslist = new ArrayList<Drink>();
}

public Collection<Drink> getDrinksList(){

    return drinkslist;
}

public void addDrink(Drink drink){

    drinkslist.add(drink)
}

}
```

my question is: I have to insert also the collection clientlist in the class RoomWithBar or the collection automatically is inherited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats what `protected` modifier does.

```
protected Collection<Client> clientlist;
```

Now, `clientlist` will be accessible in derived classes.

For details [click here.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Access_Modifiers)

Answer (score 1):

The collection is automatically inherited by the derived class.

However, since `clientlist` is declared `private`, the derived class won't be able to access it directly: you'll either need to create a getter method or change the visibility of `clientList` to, e.g., `protected`.

Answer (score 0):

`clientlist` is a private field, so the subclass could not access it. so in `RoomWithBar` class you won't be able to reach it either.

When you're calling the super constructor in `RoomWithBar` class the initialization will be done by the constructor of the `Room` class.

However I would highly recommend to declare the `clientlist` field with `final` keyword to prevent uninitialized field, because if you forgot to call the `super` constructor your `clientlist` field will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to access the collection from the Room class, since it's private.

You'll need to either specify methods to interact with it in the Room class (like addClient, in my opinion, the best solution), or make it protected and handle that in the RoomWithBar class.

If you simply change the visibility, then you'll have to implement the interaction in every extending class you implement in the future (like RoomWithJacuzzi or wtv), which isn't that great of a design. If you **do** need specific behavior, you can always override the methods for handling  clients, but these should be defined in the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `clientlist` is declared as private, you cannot access them using `RoomWithBar` or even with `Room` object.

Make it as protected or public. Or declare public method in `Room` to add or get the elements from `clientlist`. You can access these methods from the object of `RoomWithBar`

Answer (score 0):

As declare the any specifier object/variable are inherited by the derived class but declare with the private then you can't access directly that object/variable